# Rollup proxy configuration causes the short circuit in the client-server

Tags: proxy, rollupjs

In my `rollup.config.js` file, I have added the following lines to proxy the requests destined to the client-server to the backend as such:

```
!production && localdev({
  dirs: ['public'],
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 9876,
  proxy: [{ from: '/api/*', to: 'localhost:8080' }],
}),
```

, but this causes the server to short circuit and give the prompt below:

```
yarn run v1.22.11
warning package.json: No license field
$ rollup -c -w
rollup v2.58.0
bundles src/main.ts → public\build\bundle.js...
LiveReload enabled
[2021-10-13 12:03:20] ÔÜí´©Ädev-server proxying from /api/* to localhost:8080
Done in 3.63s.
```

it should be working until it is explicitly interrupted, though.

Answer (score 0):

change `localhost:8080` to `http://localhost:8080`. it's bad that it doesn't shout the error.

See https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3717
and https://github.com/pearofducks/rollup-plugin-dev